# Displaying a div based on a dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a part of jsp code like this :

```
<div>
<label>Choose the type of procedure you want :</label><select id="proc-type">
<option value="with-param">With parameters</option>
<option value="without-param">Without parameters</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Now, if user chooses with parameters, the following div should be displayed :

```
<div class="drop" id="drop">
<label> Select Procedure (without parameters) : </label> <select id="combobox" name="combobox">
<option>proc 1</option>
<option>proc 2</option>
</select>
```

And, if its without parameters, this should be displayed

```
<div class="drop" id="drop">
<label> Select Procedure (without parameters) : </label> <select id="combobox" name="combobox">
<option>proc 3</option>
<option>proc 4</option>
</select>
<label>Parameter : </label> <textarea rows=1 cols=30 ></textarea> <br>
<label>Parameter : </label> <textarea rows=1 cols=30 ></textarea> <br>
</div>
```

I've tried the jquery code as :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".dropdown").hide();
$(".drop").hide();
$("#proc-type").change( function(){
    var opt="";

    opt= $parseInt($("select option: selected").val());

    if(opt == "with-param"){
        ("#dropdown").show(700);
    }
    else {
        ("#drop").show(700);
    }
});
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work.Can anyone suggest me how to do it ?

Comment: you have same ids for multiple elem instances in your page and its invalid markup.

Answer (score 0):

The standard javascript function is `parseInt`, not `$parseInt`. And, from what I understand, you don't need it - `val()` already returns the string value.

Also, to get the value from a `<select>`, you can call `val()` on it directly. So, your line becomes:

```
opt = $(this).val();
```

Since the `this` becomes the element on which the event happened - the select itself.

At last, you might want to `hide()` the other div after showing the correct one, in case the user changes its mind.

Answer (score 0):

well, first of all, ID should always be unique (that is why it is called id) .
so make sure you have unique id for all elements.

secondly, i cannot find any elements with id as dropdown in your code ( are you missing that?)

anyways ,

the solution,

**HTML**

```
<div class="drop" id="drop1"> //<---here
<label> Select Procedure (without parameters) : </label> 
<select id="combobox1" name="combobox">
  <option>proc 1</option>
  <option>proc 2</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="drop" id="drop2"> //<---here
<label> Select Procedure (without parameters) : </label> 
<select id="combobox2" name="combobox">
  <option>proc 3</option>
  <option>proc 4</option>
</select>
<label>Parameter : </label> <textarea rows=1 cols=30 ></textarea> <br>
<label>Parameter : </label> <textarea rows=1 cols=30 ></textarea> <br>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".drop").hide();
  $("#proc-type").change( function(){

    if(this.value == "with-param"){
        $("#drop1").show(700);
        $("#drop2").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#drop2").show(700);
        $("#drop1").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have same ids for multiple element instances that way, id should be unique per element in a single page. i suggest you to change like this:

```
<div class='wrapperdiv'>
  <div class="drop with-param">
    <label> Select Procedure (with parameters) : </label> 
    <select id="combobox1" name="combobox1">
       <option>proc 1</option>
       <option>proc 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="drop without-param">
    <label> Select Procedure (without parameters) : </label> 
    <select id="combobox1" name="combobox1">
       <option>proc 1</option>
       <option>proc 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

in css hide the divs:

```
.drop{ display:none; }
```

so your jquery should be like this:

```
$('#proc-type').on('change', function(){
    var div2show = this.value;
    if(div2show == 'with-param'){
       $('.with-param').show();
       $('.without-param').hide();
    }else{
       $('.with-param').hide();
       $('.without-param').show();
    }
}).change();
```

or this *(If your both div are contained in some wrapper div)*:

```
$('#proc-type').on('change', function(){
    var div2show = this.value;
    $('.'+div2show).show().siblings('div').hide();
}).change();
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3NMVX/)

Comment: Oops.. Sorry.. Actually the id's were different. I didn't paste it properly